# Group by key error for dask dataframe map_partitions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

I'm trying to run a dask job on a big dataframe. Essentially there are two groups within the dataframe, and I'm performing a fuzzy match between them. One group is the group doing the matching, and the other group is the one being matched. The matching group has value 3.0, and the matched group has value in either 1.5 or 2.0.

My code works for the most part, but after its completion (which takes a couple hours), it gives me a key error for the matching group.

Here is my code:

```
for i in [2.0,1.5]:
    FuzzyWuzzyResults = emb.map_partitions(
        lambda df: df.groupby('phase').get_group(3.0)['drugs'].apply(
            fuzzy_match, args=(df.groupby('phase').get_group(i)['drugs'],
            fuzz.token_sort_ratio,85)), meta=('results')
        ).compute()
```

It'll work for most partitions of the huge pandas dataframe, but at the end, I get a couple "KeyError 3.0" errors, and the code breaks in between. How can I fix this? If possible, I would not want to use groupby and rather break the og dataframe into two and apply the dask job that way, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do any of your partitions not contain any phase=3.0 values?

Comment: I am unsure how I would find that out, though I believe that each partition should have phase=3.0 values. From what I understand the partitions are determined automatically through the dask implementation.

Comment: Your symptoms sound like they may be missing, that the error comes from `.get_group(3.0)`.

Comment: It's weird, but after I got that initial error, I restarted the program and got no mention of the KeyError again. I don't understand why that occurs. Maybe random partitioning gives some partitions without phase=3.0 values.